# Можете(,) кто-нибудь(,) мне помочь?

Tags: запятые

Нужны ли запятые?

1. Можете(,) кто-нибудь(,) мне помочь?
2. Можете(,) кто-то(,) принести воду?
3. Можете(,) хоть кто-нибудь(,) моего бычка подоить, пока я в загороде?

Comment: подоить, уехать в пригород, но уехать загород, пока я загородом.

Comment: А бычка под**о**ить – это как? :))

Comment: ну это как бабушка козла доила в анекдоте.